# How to show view while scrolling and hide view after scrolling stop in android

Tags: android, view, scrollview, show-hide

I have a linear layout view with some button  at the bottom of my layout.. Layout contains lots of elements so I haveadded scrollview to show all contents.

Now when i scroll up or down i want to hide my bottom linear layout content and as soon as user stop scrolling listview I want to show it again.

Can any one suggest me some solution to achieve this.
Any help is appropriated
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try to implement `OnScrollListener` of your `ScrollView`. It has a method:

```
        /**
         * Callback method to be invoked while the list view or grid view is being scrolled. If the
         * view is being scrolled, this method will be called before the next frame of the scroll is
         * rendered. In particular, it will be called before any calls to
         * {@link Adapter#getView(int, View, ViewGroup)}.
         *
         * @param view The view whose scroll state is being reported
         *
         * @param scrollState The current scroll state. One of {@link #SCROLL_STATE_IDLE},
         * {@link #SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL} or {@link #SCROLL_STATE_IDLE}.
         */
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState);
```

When scroll state changes you can `setVisibility()` to a `Button` you want to show/hide.